# reference to partial object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object and it's typed

```
interface formDataType {
  tesla: {
    made: string
  },
  ford: {
    made: string
  }
}
const formData: formDataType = {
    "tesla": {
      "made":"2021"
    },
    "ford": {
      "made": "2022"
    }
  };
```

then I've a function where its argument is one of `[string]:{made: string}`, how can I use back formDataType? is there something like `objectOf formDataType`?

demo https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-cwv9p

Comment: Do you mean the argument of your next function can be e.g. `{ford: {made: "2022"}}`?

Comment: Please provide a plaintext [mre] in the post itself that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Wyb22w) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. (External IDE links are great but do not take the place of a plaintext example in the post itself).  You should include the intended use case, like how you plan to call `handleChange()`, since it's not clear what you're asking for.  Good luck!

Comment: @ghybs yes, jsejcksn answered it but it require breaking down my type

Comment: @jcalz someone just answered it, my question was fine.

Comment: Well, in jsejcksn's answer, the argument is e.g. `{made: "2022"}`.

Comment: It's unfortunately still not clear to me whether you desire the argument to be `{ford: {made: "2022"}}` or `{made: "2022"}` or something else, or what you intend to do in the implementation of the function.  It's good that you've gotten an answer that helps you; now you can help future readers by clarifying the question with a proper [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a type to use in your `FormDataType`, then reuse that type in your function:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAahAWBLAxgGwgEQsAho1AzlALxQDeUAtjgCYQBcUBwATogHYDmUAvgNwAoAaEhQAYgHsWlDDlwAVcNFJkBUKADMpNRnCRpM2PIUHrgEAqhy6EKdFlz4Cg-kID0bqPPjQtqVBIA7hzciETAPkw4lNAiEAA0UIFswObsUACuBCFQEdAAShDI2pnA+Iig9AIeuUriUjJyOIqipIXFLDQAPADkWp09UAA+UD3mljg9iXp2ho6EAHyCAsXszJoNsriMktJbzXUqarkWVoxk1HSMPQBMAAw3AIw9PPHH-Trklwyj9zc3LzergEGgy7GQZQk6RoEgAyhIYhEQgB1CrwGYGBzGIgACjo8wINn09iMTgAlORjjVVgQJOgAHQBTh40mEMkuARAA)

```ts
type VehicleDetails = { made: string };

type FormDataType = {
  ford: VehicleDetails;
  tesla: VehicleDetails;
};

// The following is the same type, written using the Record utility:
// type FormDataType = Record<'ford' | 'tesla', VehicleDetails>;

const formData: FormDataType = {
  tesla: {made: '2021'},
  ford: {made: '2022'},
};

function doSomethingWithVehicleDetails (details: VehicleDetails) {
  // console.log(details);
}
```

---

Update in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71088142/reference-to-partial-object-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment125666340_71088548):

You can also derive a union of all the types of the values of the keys in your `FormData` type (and if they're all the same type, the union will effectively be that one type):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYBECGw0BVzQLxQDeAUFFAGaIAmAXEVEmlRHQM7AICWAdgOZQBfANykowCKwA2aOoQZMWUdlz6CRw4sVCQoANQgALTgGNJEFBEydJrKAXjJ0mHJADaAawgg45WIlQY2LgAuiLE5ACu3MbAnHDcUFRwAMpwSJZGfADqnMAG+kam5pZo1rYAFMxWNnQFJmYW1awAlESiAPTtUMbxrHBmAHSScLyVJWXN6sRAA)

```ts
type FormDataType = {
  ford: { made: string };
  tesla: { made: string };
};

type VehicleDetails = FormDataType[keyof FormDataType];

function doSomethingWithVehicleDetails (details: VehicleDetails) {
  // console.log(details);
}
```

Comment: this is the only way i can think of, damn I've to refactor a bunch of types just to solve one 'any' issue

Comment: @JenniferAlexis In your `FormDataType`, are all the string keys the same type?

Comment: yes. is it good to use capital letter for type/interface?

Comment: this worked! but what if I want to extend another property in any of the object? like adding {somethingNewBrand: {made:'2021', isInStock: true}}?

Comment: @JenniferAlexis If you read [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html), you'll find that `PascalCase` is idiomatic. (Just like the name: `TypeScript`)

Comment: thanks for making my day, please teach me how to extend a new property?

Comment: @JenniferAlexis If you ask a new question and want to link to it here, I'll take a look. And you are welcome.